# Offline geocoding and reverse geocoding for android

Tags: android, geocoding, openstreetmap, offline, reverse-geocoding

I'm developing an android application that cannot use internet and need to deal with maps and positioning.

Download OpenStreetMaps data seens to be a good solution to access map information offline. However, I need some basic algorithms running locally on the cellphone, like geocoding and reverse geocoding.

**Does anybody know a library for android that can consume offline openstreetmap data and provive geocoding and reverse geocoding on the cellphone?**

Comment: Can you use gps or wifi location to get coordinates or is that not allowed either? You could use the IP lookup to get a rough estimate of the user's location (not always accurate) but that would require internet access too.

Comment: I can use GPS, so my current coordinates is not a problem. What I need is, given the coordinates, discover which street I'm.

Comment: Does this work for you? http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/82/offline-map-browser-on-android-with-offline-search

Comment: Thank you for your tip, but those are end user apps. I actually need to develop and app that use some features listed on the post you recommended. Thu, I need something like a library.

Comment: You could use GraphHopper for find the street name from a GPS point but not the opposite

Answer (score 1):

For geocoding you could use this approach:

1. Create addresses index as sqlite/spatialite database, as I know there it could be used in android apps.
2. Search among this index using Full Text Search extension or without, I can't say which one will be better. Also you can use spatialite extension to create human readable text for coordinates.

You can create index in one of these ways:

- Using local instance of OSM Nominatim. It will create his own version of index into your local PostGIS database, after that, you could dump it into the sqlite.
- You can use https://github.com/kiselev-dv/gazetteer it could generate you such index in json or csv, so you could convert it into sqlite db.

If you want more powerful SDK, check this http://developer.skobbler.com/?source=scout#tour

Comment: Primitive text searches won't be sufficient for a complex task such as (reverse) geocoding.

Comment: @scai You could look sources of one of these projects [Pelias](https://github.com/pelias/pelias) [Nominatim](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim) or [Osmand](https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand) For geocoding all of them uses text search. For reverse geocoding they use rather simple geospatial query to obtain highway in some radius and enclosing boundaries. Of course you can create more complicated solution. Anyway, if you want offline geocoder, first you need index, second you need text queries, third spatial queries. You may do more, but not least.